# Java Timer Error

Tags: java, timer

I have just recently been learning about Java Timers, but I have been having a problem actually using them.
Before I begin to dive deeper into learning about GUI programming, I would like to fully understand Java Timers, being as important as they are.
So far I have two separate classes, a listener class and a main class.
The main class is where I get the error in Eclipse.

```
package TimTest;

import java.util.Timer;

public class TimerTest  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TimList listener = new TimList();

        Timer timer;
        timer = new Timer(2000, listener );
        timer.start()   
    }
}
```

And here is the listener class:

```
package TimTest;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class TimList implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        System.out.println("TiMeR-TeSt");       
    }
}
```

So my question is, what am I doing wrong?
As far as I can see everything is done correctly.

Comment: What error,, is the IDE referring to? Seems like two I can point out straight away. First the use of uninitalized local variable `timer` inside main, try using `Timer timer = new Timer (2000, listener), or `Timer timer = null;` and rest as is Second, the absence of `;` colons after `timer.start()`. See if this sort thingies out. Moreover, learn about [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

Comment: Thanks for pointing those two errors out, but there seems to be more. http://i.imgur.com/ZgnrZay.jpg

Comment: Your example isn't going to do much (once it's working), as `javax.swing.Timer` kind of needs a running GUI around it to work

Comment: @Trtld: Ohho, you are using the wrong import. You want to use `javax.swing.Timer` though you using `java.util.Timer`.

Comment: Okay, I'll make my test program a little more complex and see if that works out. ty

Comment: Hey that worked!  but as MadProgrammer said, it doesn't do much.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing semi-colon here:

```
timer.start();
             ^ expected here `;`
```

As per posted image, you need swing timer instead of util, change your import for `Timer` to:

```
import java.swing.Timer;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah  , you need to end the line

```
   timer.start()
```

with a semi-colon ,then it changes to  -->

```
  timer.start();
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies, but I still get this error: http://i.imgur.com/ZgnrZay.jpg

Comment: Hey , check out my new answer , it might solves the problem .